# Amazon S3 Object Lambda: “406-Not Acceptable Response” in HTTP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am building a REST API using only Amazon [S3 Object Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/olap-writing-lambda.html). It turns out that there is only a limited set of HTTP Status Code that I can return to the client. For instance I cannot use “406-Not Acceptable” response.

So my question is simply: is Amazon S3 Object Lambda a good technology for building REST API ? Or should I glue it to another AWS service ?

For reference:

- http://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_s3_1_1_model_1_1_write_get_object_response_request.html#a27d917274b7040778091026a1ec55d22

> ```
> The integer status code for an HTTP response of a corresponding GetObject request.
> Status Codes
> 200 - OK
> 206 - Partial Content
> 304 - Not Modified
> 400 - Bad Request
> 401 - Unauthorized
> 403 - Forbidden
> 404 - Not Found
> 405 - Method Not Allowed
> 409 - Conflict
> 411 - Length Required
> 412 - Precondition Failed
> 416 - Range Not Satisfiable
> 500 - Internal Server Error
> 503 - Service Unavailable
> ```

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

Comment: *"is S3 Object Lambda a good technology for building REST API ?"* - no, that is not a good use nor is it at all intended for that. What makes you think it is? You should use a "normal" AWS Lambda and put an API Gateway in front.

Comment: @luk2302 I've stopped using the API gateway for any binary data due to the performance and limitations of the system. e.g. There is a 10 meg payload limit, this based on the base64 length and not the size of the file.

Comment: Then use S3 presigned urls. Let your lambda create them, send them to the client and let the client upload to s3.